# How to: Translating language for multiple products/categories

Tags: localisation, magmi

My current setup is like this (new install).

- main website

  - main website store

    - store view English
    - store view German

Using Magmi, I know how to create my category structure (on the fly) - and how to add my 100 products to the default category.

However, how should I handle it, when I want to have my same product catalog translated into German when that store view is selected?

From what I can tell, this is a two part problem.

1. How to handle from a Magento perspective:

   - Do I create two unique root categories for each language and duplicate the product list into each?
   - Do I have one list/category, by somehow manage the translation for name and description somewhere else??           .....  I'm a bit lost!
2. How to then manage that with Magmi... but maybe its better to resolve point 1 first. Hopefully it becomes clear and simple to me by then :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I was able to solve this by trial and error.

Using Magmi, you use the standard columns such as:

`sku   category_reset  websites    name    attribute_set   type    store   categories  weight  price   qty description short_description   status  tax_class_id    visibility`

and for one product, you enter it twice - changing the name and description to the translated versions. Of course, you also need to change the **store** to German in the 2nd entry.

The big catch - which I somehow missed in all my googling, was you also need to include the **url_key** field - and manually set this for the two languages (ie, product1-english, product1-german). This is the part that will complete the translation functionality.

I think you might also need to hard code the url-path, but I haven't tested that yet.

I hope this helps someone - as it drove me crazy for the last 4 hours :)

Comment: What happens if you leave out `url_key`

Answer (score 5):

Most folks have the same products, but change the field values based on the "store view". For example:

- Catalog, Manage Products, and set the "store view" to "All Store Views".
- Add Product, and fill in the values with the "default" language.
  Save.
- Open the same product again, then select the "store view" of
  the alternative language. Un-check the values that need to change, and update those. Save.

You should now have the same product in both stores. And because you added values for both "default" and "2nd language" those will be shown appropriately when a customer selects a language.

Comment: OK, thanks - I got it. Now I just need to work out how to do that in Magmi.. I'll do some testing and post results back here. Many Thanks for your help.