# translate categories (using Magmi)

Tags: category, magmi

[In another questions of mine](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25096/how-to-translating-language-for-multiple-products-categories/25201#25201), I was able to import multiple products, and change the language of them, based on the store and url_key settings like this:

```
sku;store;name;url_key;
test#001;english;car;car-key
test#001;german;auto;auto-key
```

and this allows me in Magmi to import 100s of products, which can be shown in native language when using the language switcher menu etc. Great.

However - I cannot manage the categories in the same way. If I do this:

```
sku;store;name;url_key;categories
test#001;english;car;car-key;english-cat-name
test#001;german;auto;auto-key;german-cat-name
```

.. using on-the-fly-categories, the categories themselves are visible from both the english and german views.

How can I manage this in Magmi - with 100s of categories, I don't want to have to adjust them by hand. I am hoping there's a way to automate this somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, will it help if I provide more information - or rephrase the question? Essentially, I am asking this "How can I manage the translation of many categories easily?". Perhaps this will give a different answer?

Comment: any update as how to do that with one root instead of multiple root?

Comment: UPDATE 2016-07-16: Translation is now possible with Magmi http://stackoverflow.com/a/38406986/204610

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full category tree need to be set for each locale, with associated store view.

Then , you need to use the [multistore syntax for category plugin](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer#Multiple_Store_roots_management) for defining localized categories under each root category (one per localized category tree).

Comment: thanks Dweeves for your feedback. In the short-term, I used a reduced category set of around 20, and changed them by hand. I was then able to use your tool to import the group products I needed into each store using the store ID. All worked nicely.

I'm wondering if there is any major impact or pro/con in having separate trees? The pro is, I can use your tool to set it up. What could be the con? Thanks!!

Comment: any update as how to do that with one root instead of multiple root?

Comment: UPDATE 2016-07-16: Translation is now possible with Magmi http://stackoverflow.com/a/38406986/204610